# How can I create a new order status / state in my module on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, orders, magento2.1.6

I'd like to create a new order state like **processing, complete and etc..** Using my custom module (without using the admin panel).

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the block, controller or model of your custom module

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Block\Path;

class Sample
extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
{
    protected $status;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status $status,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function setCustomStatus(){
        // create status
        $this->status->setData('status', 'your_status') //code
             ->setData('label', 'Your New Status') //title
             ->save();

        // assign your state in to Magento order states
        $this->status->assignState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_NEW, true);
    }

}
```

Here is the list of Magento order states, which is found in file `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order`

```
const STATE_NEW = 'new';

const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';

const STATE_PROCESSING = 'processing';

const STATE_COMPLETE = 'complete';

const STATE_CLOSED = 'closed';

const STATE_CANCELED = 'canceled';

const STATE_HOLDED = 'holded';

const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW = 'payment_review';
```

Comment: how to do it in custom module ? you mentioned to edit in core file

Comment: First part is how you do it in your module, it's not editing core files.

Comment: add di code for both class so it will clear confusion for new magento2 developer and also mention module xml i feel its very imp

Answer (score 3):

This should be done by a data patch these days.
First create the data patch file:

```
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-patch <module-name> <patch-name>
```

Then add and adjust the following code in the created patch file `apply()` method:

```
    // Add status
    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertOnDuplicate(
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('sales_order_status'),
        ['status' => 'code', 'label' => 'Label']
    );

    // Add status to state
    $states = [
        [
            'status'     => 'code',
            'state'      => 'complete',
            'is_default' => 0,
            'visible_on_front' => 1
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($states as $state) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertOnDuplicate(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('sales_order_status_state'),
            $state
        );
    }
```

After this, run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and the status will be added to database tables `sales_order_status` and `sales_order_status_state`.

Answer (score 0):

Also can be create through **UpgradeData** from your custom module. You can add new state and status using below code and also assign status to state.

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {


if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0', '<')) {

        /**
         * Install order status
         */
        $data = [];
        $statuses = [
        'custom_status1' => __('Custom Status 1'),
        'custom_status2' => __('Custom Status 2'),
        ];

        foreach ($statuses as $code => $info) {
            $data[] = ['status' => $code, 'label' => $info];
        }

        $setup->getConnection()->insertArray($setup->getTable('sales_order_status'), ['status', 'label'], $data);

        /**
         * Install order states
         */
        $data = [];

        $states = [
        'custom_state1' => [
        'label' => __('Custom State 1'),
        'statuses' => ['custom_status1' => ['default' => '0']],
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        ],
        'custom_state2' => [
        'label' => __('Custom State 1'),
        'statuses' => ['custom_status2' => ['default' => '1']],
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        ]
        ];

        foreach ($states as $code => $info) {
            if (isset($info['statuses'])) {
                foreach ($info['statuses'] as $status => $statusInfo) {
                    $data[] = [
                    'status' => $status,
                    'state' => $code,
                    'is_default' => is_array($statusInfo) && isset($statusInfo['default']) ? 1 : 0,
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Assign status to state
         */
        $setup->getConnection()->insertArray(
            $setup->getTable('sales_order_status_state'),
            ['status', 'state', 'is_default'],
            $data
            );

    }

}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can new state & status of order using installData script in your modules. You can try below code :

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
     public function __construct(
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory

    ) {
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;       
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {


        $setup->startSetup();

        $salesSetup = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Install eav entity types to the eav/entity_type table
         */
        $salesSetup->installEntities();

        /**
         * Install order statuses from config
         */
        $data1 = [];
        $statuses = [
            'custom_status1' => __('Custom Status 1'),
            'custom_status2' => __('Custom Status 2'),


        ];
        foreach ($statuses as $code => $info) {
            $data1[] = ['status' => $code, 'label' => $info];
        }
        //$setup->getConnection()->insertArray($setup->getTable('sales_order_status'), ['status', 'label'], $data1);
        $setup->getConnection()->insertArray($setup->getTable('sales_order_status'), ['status', 'label'], $data1);

        /**
         * Install order states from config
         */
        $data2 = [];
        $states = [
            'custom_status1' => [
                'label' => __('Custom Status 1'),
                'statuses' => ['custom_status1' => ['default' => '1']],
                'visible_on_front' => true,
            ],
            'custom_status2' => [
                'label' => __('Custom Status 2'),
                'statuses' => ['custom_status2' => ['default' => '1']],
                'visible_on_front' => true,
            ]

        ];

        foreach ($states as $code => $info) {
            if (isset($info['statuses'])) {
                foreach ($info['statuses'] as $status => $statusInfo) {
                    $data2[] = [
                        'status' => $status,
                        'state' => $code,
                        'is_default' => is_array($statusInfo) && isset($statusInfo['default']) ? 1 : 0,
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        /** Assign status to state */

        $setup->getConnection()->insertArray(
            $setup->getTable('sales_order_status_state'),
            ['status', 'state', 'is_default'],
            $data2
        );

        /** Update visibility for states */
        $states = ['custom_status1','custom_status2'];
        foreach ($states as $state) {
            $setup->getConnection()->update(
                $setup->getTable('sales_order_status_state'),
                ['visible_on_front' => 1],
                ['state = ?' => $state]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```